# Surfaces of Finite Topological Type

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology

When I read some papers, I see the term 'Surfaces of Finite Topological Type'. But it is not defined. I guess that it is used for surfaces with finite Euler characteristic. But I could not be sure.

Answer (score 5):

A surface $S$ has finite type if there exists a compact surface $F$ and a finite subset $A \subset F$ such that $S$ is homeomorphic to $F-A$.

To speak about "finite Euler characteristic" is somewhat fishy: the Euler characteristic is not even well-defined unless some other quantities are finite. At a minimum, you need all of the homology groups $H_n(S;\mathbb{Z})$ to be finitely generated in order to even define the Euler characteristic (namely as the alternating sum of the ranks of those homology groups).

However, it is true that a surface $S$ has finite type if and only if all of its homology groups $H_n(S;\mathbb{Z})$ have finite rank. The trouble with this statement is that it is hard to prove the "if" direction.

Comment: Is the "if" direction of the statement "finite type if and only if all homology groups have finite rank" special to surfaces?  Or is it more general?

Comment: It's far from true in general. Starting in dimension 3 there even exist contractible manifolds which are not of finite type in the sense I have defined. The [Whitehead manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold) is an example, and it is not of finite type even in the more general sense appropriate to high dimensional manifolds that is mentioned in the answer of @AndreaM.M.

Comment: Oh, of course. I was thinking of "finite type" as "embeddable as an open subset of a  closed manifold", and was missing the part your and Andrea's answer that the image would end up being dense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An open (non-compact and complete) manifold M is said to have finite topological type, if it is homeomorphic to the interior of a compact manifold with boundary. Recall that according to Cheeger-Gromoll’s soul theorem, an open manifold with non-negative sectional curvature always has finite topological type, which is false if one relaxes the assumption on sectional curvature to Ricci curvature for the case of dimension ≥ 4.

Comment: (And the last sentence is a result due to Sha and Yang:  Examples of manifolds of positive Ricci curvature, J. Differential Geom. 29(1): 95-103 (1989) )

Answer (score 2):

From W.H. Fleming's *Nondegenerate Surfaces of Finite Topological Type*, the topological type of a surface $M$ (I've taken the liberty to modernize notation here) with Euler characteristic $\chi(M)$ and $v$ punctures, the topological type of $M$ is $$ \tau =(\chi(M), v , \epsilon)$$ 
where $\epsilon$ denotes whether $M$ is orientable or no. Further $M$ is said to be of finite topological type iff it is of the type of a compact 2-manifold.